# Pure JavaScript workaround for localStorage issue after 5.1 IOS update?

Tags: javascript, ios, html

Is there any known solution for the problem with deletion of persistent data for pure HTML5 apps that do not use PhoneGap ?

Comment: You can always dump data to a flat file.